# Cannot properly get react router dom to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I currently have this code, when I try to implement react-router-dom in my application:

main.js:

```
"use strict";
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const BrowserRender = require('react-router-dom').BrowserRouter;
const App = require('./components/app');

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRender> <App /> </BrowserRender>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

app.js:

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
const React = require('react');
const Header = require('./common/header');
const Routes = require('../routes');

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Routes />
    </div>
);

module.exports = App;
```

and routes.js:

```
"use strict";
const React = require('react');
const Router = require('react-router-dom');
const Route = Router.Route;
const Switch = Router.Switch;
const Home = require('./components/homepage');
const AuthorPage = require('./components/authors/authorPage');
const About = require('./components/about/aboutpage');

const Routes = () => (
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/authors" component={AuthorPage}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
)

module.exports = Routes;
```

However, when I run this on the browser I only get:

```
Uncaught Error: A <Router> may have only one child element
```

I have tried many things, at first I was using React-Router as is, but then I saw that it has been reimplemented as 'react-router-dom' and I followed the steps of an internet tutorial but I can't see to get it right. Any ideas?

Comment: From which file you are getting the error? app.js or routes.js?

Comment: Try my solution, although I'm not sure about it, just give it a shot and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put header inside routes as `browser router` will accept only one child.

You need to adjust header inside your routes.

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
const React = require('react');

const Routes = require('../routes');

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Routes />
    </div>
);

module.exports = App;
```

If you want `Header` to render always, do this,

```
"use strict";
const React = require('react');
const Router = require('react-router-dom');
const Route = Router.Route;
const Switch = Router.Switch;
const Header = require('./common/header');
const Home = require('./components/homepage');
const AuthorPage = require('./components/authors/authorPage');
const About = require('./components/about/aboutpage');

const Routes = () => (
    <div>
        <Route path = "" component = {Header} />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/authors" component={AuthorPage}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
)

module.exports = Routes;
```

Comment: @RenéVidrialesTrujillo See this [pen](https://codepen.io/anuragasaurus/pen/OgRejK?editors=0010), its same code as yours and its working there. I think there is some other problem.

Comment: I don't see the routing there 

Comment: I'll try putting them in the same exact file and see if that works!

Answer (score 0):

Router should be imported from 'react-router', not 'react-router-dom' (in routes.js).

**edit**

I tried the following and it works. It is just a "create-react-app" base app with react-router@4 and react-router-dom@4 added.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Routes from './Routes';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Routes.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Home</div>;
  }
}

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>About</div>;
  }
}

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

I'm using import instead of require, but other than that I cannot see any reason why my code should work and yours shouldn't.

Comment: `react-router-dom` reimports all imports of `react-router`, so you just need to use `react-router-dom`

Comment: I know, just wanted to try the suggestion. However, trying that or using the code I posted I get te same error :( I'm getting tired of it